# Can't run Unity3d app in Xcode iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I was able to open the app in my actual iphone6. But the result page of the app didn't show any search result and it just has the title of result page and a scroll bar. So I try to run the app in iPhone simulator in Xcode. But after I click the app logo in simulator, its just a black screen. Nothing happen after that. What is happening? And I only got the things in below pictures under a tag called Thread 1.  I am new to Unity3d and Xcode. Please help! Thank you!

I have Unity3d 5.3.4f1, Xcode 7.1.

[image]

[image]

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash.

Comment: If the problem is about crashing and freezing,post the Unity version and the Xcode version.

Answer (score 6):

Since it worked on the physical devices but not on the simulator. Change the **Target SDK** to ***Simulator SDK*** then build the project again. Look at the circled part of the image below. If still not working, the Unity and Xcode version.

[image]

Comment: I have already selected Simulator SDK for the target SDK. Is there other reason that causes it not working? But thank you for responding tho!

Comment: @ChristineZheng What Unity version and What Xcode version? What is the SDK version you are building to? I can't help if I don't know these.....

Comment: I have Unity3d 5.3.4f1, Xcode 7.1. Android Studio 2.1. Let me know if u need more info. Thank you!

Comment: @ChristineZheng Change **Scripting Backend** in the picture above from **IL2CPP** to **Mono2x**. Build and let me know what happens.

Comment: It didn't compile. I got Error building Player: UnityException: Cross compilation failed.

Comment: @ChristineZheng Didn't get a notification. Came back because I saw your new question. There are still few things left. Set the bitcode of off before building. https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/207942813-How-can-I-disable-Bitcode-support- Use that script and build your project it will set bitcode to off. Let me know what happens